# How can i solve this java lang error?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to solve this java lang error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre11/com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre11.SignUpOrLogInActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre11.SignUpOrLogInActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2039)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre11.SignUpOrLogInActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2030)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have checked again and again the code and i can't find what is making the app crash, maybe some fresh eyes can help to find the issue.

Here is the SignUpOrSignIn class

```
public class SignUpOrLogInActivity extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    Button signIn;
    Button signUp;    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signinorsignup_activity,container,false);   

        Button signIn = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.login);
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });

        Button signUp = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.signup);
        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),SignUpActivity.class));
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, Session state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#67AAE4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"/>


    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

MANIFEST

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".ParseStarter">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SignUpOrLogInActivity"

            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity >


        <activity android:name=".DispatchActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>


        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

"CORRECTED MANIFEST"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre11" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".ParseStarter">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >




            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity >


        <activity android:name=".DispatchActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>


        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone figure out what is making the app crash?

Thanks very much for reading :)

Comment: can you show me code how u start this fragment?

Comment: remove  `SignUpOrLogInActivity `  from manifest

Comment: The logcat states that you are casting the `SignupOrLoginActivity` to an `Activity` when it is actually a `Fragment`. I cannot see where you are making this call, it does not appear to be in the code you have posted.

Comment: actually that is the fragment that the app shows when first opened

Comment: Look at @Eran's answer, I think he is right. Could you inspect your `AndroidManifest` to see if you are declaring this Fragment as an Activity?

Comment: I just put the code of the corrected manifest, but it keeps giving me the same error, do you mind if you give it a look @CodeMonkey?

Comment: Is the logcat reporting the same error? The reason I ask is that you have four other "Activities" listed in your Manifest which might also be Fragments as far as I know (and I don't know if they are being instantiated).

Comment: the other ones are real activities

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67512/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-sebastian-delgado-diaz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SignUpOrLogInActivity` extends `Fragment`. I'm assuming, based on the name, that this class is declared in the manifest as an Activity, which makes Android expect it to be a sub-class of Activity.

A `Fragment` must be contained in an `Activity`, so you need to create a class that extends `Activity` and contains your `Fragment` (which I would rename to something that doesn't contain the word Activity, since it's confusing). Your Android manifest should declare that activity class as the activity from which your app is launched.

Comment: And probably is set as the launch activity.

Comment: i'm a little bit confused, i just put the manifest on the question

Comment: i know the mistake, but then what do i have to do with the intent filter?

Comment: `SignUpOrLogInActivity` extends `Fragment`, yet you declare it in your Manifest as an `Activity`. These are two separate things and that is why you are getting the error. You need to declare your Fragment's parent Activity instead of your Fragment in the Manifest.

Comment: I just put the code of the corrected manifest, but it keeps giving me the same error, do you mind if you give it a look @CodeMonkey?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SignUpOrLogInActivity extends Fragment
```

this is a fragment, and you are casting it to an activity.

You need to typecast it to a fragment for it to work

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sebasdeldihotmail.mediocre11.SignUpOrLogInActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```